# Statistics regression problem

Tags: statistics

Suppose a regression will be fit to the n points

$(x_1, y_1),(x_2, y_2), . . . ,(x_n, y_n)$

where $x_2 = x_3 = · · · = x_n$ but where $x_1 ≠ x_2$.

Show that the line must pass through the point $(x_1, y_1)$

Comment: Is $ x_1=\ldots =x_n$ ?

Comment: This must be a typo. Otherwise all the points are on the same vertical line.

Comment: Should it be $x_1 \not= x_2$? Please fix.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**:You have to start by minimizing the expression

$V=\sum_{i=2}^n \left( y_i-a-bx_2 \right) ^2+\left(y_1-a-bx_1 \right)^2 $

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial a}=-2\cdot \left(\sum_{i=2}^n \left( y_i-a-bx_2 \right) +\left(y_1-a-bx_1 \right)  \right)=0$

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial b}=-2\cdot \left(\sum_{i=2}^n \left( y_i-a-bx_2 \right)\cdot x_2 +\left(y_1-a-bx_1 \right)  \right)\cdot x_1=0$

Solve for a and b.

**Hint 2:** The expression for b is $\large{b=\frac{n\cdot ( \overline y-a)}{(n-1)\cdot x_2+x_1}}$

Comment: Thank you, I got to the point when I have an equation for b and a and I think the general idea is to make an equation of bx1+a and prove that this equals y1 but I have not been able to do this. Can you give more hints?